# Webform "Not You?" message does not appear in secondary theme area

Tags: webform-civicrm

If I set up a webform and put it in the primary theme area, I can see the "Not You?" message on top of the screen. The same webform, in a secondary theme area (a sidebar), doesn't show the "Not You?" message. Is there any way to make that message show up?

Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

We just set that "Not You?" message using standard drupal message functions (in D7 and D8). A theme will typically display such messages in a separate region above the content region. What you can try is change the Region settings -> i.e. change it from in your case Help -> Secondary.

D8 example - using Olivero Theme: works well:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference which region I set the Help block to appear in (including Seconday), it always shows up right underneath the title. But it only appears when the webform is in the Content region. If the webform is in Secondary, there is no "Not You?" message anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it's helpful to anyone else, my hacky workaround was to put a webform in the primary theme region as well as the secondary region. This webform in the primary region contains nothing but the existing contact and the Not you? option, which means it just shows a submit button and the Not you? option. Hide that button with Javascript and now you have a Not you? link that works for your secondary region webform too.